# Difficulty understanding multiple uploads in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have 2 tables: SOLICITATION and FILES

**SOLICITATION:**
id,
name,
description,
created

**FILES:**
id,
solicitation_id,
attachment,

When creating new solicitation I need to upload multiple attachments at one time, I would like to know how the code will look in the ACTION SolicitationController so that the files are sent to UPLOAD folder and names stored in the FILES table:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Solicitation();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('protocolo-success', 'Solicitation Saved!');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Solicitation Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\solicitation\models;
use app\models\User;
use Yii;

class Registros extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'mod_solicitation_records';
    }

    public $files;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id','name','location_id','user_id'], 'required'],
            [['description'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'Nº Protocolo',
            'name' => 'Nome',
            'description' => 'Descrição',
        ];
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }      

    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Location::className(), ['id' => 'location_id']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files)

Comment: Yes, I already saw this link. I'm having trouble with "how to loop and write to FILES"?

Comment: Can u upload the code of  Solicitation model only

Comment: ok, code updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one with your create action of "SOLICITATION" controller

```
public function actionCreate() {

    $model = new Registros();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->save(false))) {
        // SOLICITATION ID 
        $solicitation_id = $model->id;

        $flag = false;
        // GET INSTANCES OF FILE 
        $model->files = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'files');

        foreach ($model->files as $file) {
            $file_name = $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
            $flag = $file->saveAs("UPLOAD_FOLDER_BASEPATH/" . $file_name);
            if ($flag) {
                $fileObj = new FILES_MODEL();
                $fileObj->solicitation_id = $solicitation_id;
                $fileObj->attachment = $file_name;
                $fileObj->created = time();
                $fileObj->save(false);
            } else {
                echo "FILE UPLOAD ERROR CODE  : " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
                exit;
            }
        }
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('protocolo-success', 'Solicitation Saved!');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and View file have

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'files[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>
```

Comment: don't work. Save info in Solicitation table, but Files stay empty (no uploads in folder)

Comment: Make sure the php's  $_FILES has file

Answer (score 1):

Create a UploadForm Model using the following [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files)

Don't forget to change the namespace "app" in the model as well below and add the following line in the controller.

```
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
```

Now modify the controller action like this:

```
public function actionCreate(){
$model = new Solicitation();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
   $upload = new UploadForm();
   $upload->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
        if ($model->upload()) {
            \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('protocolo-success', 'Solicitation Saved!');
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}}
```